# Kali Linux won't apt-get update, update server down? How do I change update sources

Tags: networking, kali-linux, apt-get

I'm running Kali Linux under Parallels Desktop 10 and the system seems to work fine when trying to ping any internet site or use a browser, but when trying to run the 'apt-get update' command it fails, telling me the network image is unreachable.

The update mirror it's trying to connect to is ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de

I suspect that the error lies with that particular host, because if I go to the official Kali Linux Download site it tells me this:

```
This site can’t be reached

ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de refused to connect.
```

So the question now is if anyone else is experiencing these issues and if someone knows what updates sources I can switch to in order to get the updates working again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the **/etc/apt/sources.list** file and add links to repositories.

```
echo deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-bleeding-edge contrib non-free main >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @e.Raz I managed to add the bleeding edge repository as well but when trying to apt-get update I get the same error as before, but now I get it two times.


If you see the screenshot in the link below, you'll se that kali.org redirects to that same host which is non-responsive, so it is probably a hosting error - or are you able to update your Kali?

Screenshot: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms7u2quidn73uyv/Screenshot%202016-04-14%2013.10.56.png?dl=0)

Comment: @lundzern I don't know how exactly help you. Have you configured any proxy? If you have and you machine have not IPv6 connectivity, and try to reach an IPv6 compatible site you machine try to reach site using IPv6 and will fail. There is some help for troubleshooting net access: [link](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20846-Troubleshooting-Internet-Network-Access)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I do have the original Kali sources in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` but Kali tries to contact the mirror `ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de`. Since I'm also redirected to `ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` if I try to open e.g. http://http.kali.org/kali/README in the browser on another machine (Ubuntu, not Kali), I think the Kali server is responsible for the redirection (based on my location?). I cannot see how we could use another mirror. Perhaps we have to wait until `ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de` is fixed. :-(

Comment: Yes I think you're right. The redirection is caused by some sort of geolocation and that leaves us in the dark until the mirror is back online, thank you for confirming this issue - at least I know it is not a local problem for me. I will accept this, and @e.Raz answer because I think that both responses are relevant for this sort of error. (edit; oh, sorry, did not realize I had to pick only one answer, but in that case I think e.Raz had the most relevant)